# How do I sanitize the copy/paste buffer?

Tags: xorg, clipboard

I have noticed when I select some text, copy, and then try and paste it into, for example, gmail, it keeps the formatting.

Not once in the past 10 years has this ever been a desirable feature for me.

I am currently using glipper as my clipboard manager.

It looks like if I just select my copy/paste entry (in glipper), it causes it to get sanitized.

How can I sanitize it automatically, every time I copy/paste?

My thought was maybe I would have to write a plugin for glipper, but there has to be some setting or hook that allows me to sanitize using just x.org.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question but in some environments `Ctrl-Shift-V` pastes without formatting.

Comment: Another not-really-answer: In those cases, I first paste into a plain text editor and than copy the text again.

Comment: Have you dismissed Teekin's answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/46031/how-to-copy-paste-text-without-formatting-by-default#answer-844857 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's desired use `parcellite` you can configure it's behaviour like you wish.

http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/